# In atom autocomplete-plus suggestion has higher priority than my own snippet prefix/trigger

Tags: typescript, atom-editor, code-completion

I have a simple custom snippet

```
'.source.ts':
  'console.log()':
    'prefix': 'log'
    'body': 'console.log($1);'
```

which i use quite often.

It should work like this:

[image: my snippet in atom]

But i have [autocomplete-plus](https://github.com/atom/autocomplete-plus) installed which pushes it’s own suggestions to a higher position than my own:

[image: autocomplete-plus suggestions]

I have no var like »localStorage« in my whole project so i guess it must come from some kind of »native js functions« library of autocomplete-plus.

Is there a way to set priorities? If not, i would consider turning such general suggestions such as »localStorage« of. I couldn’t find any properties for this in autocomplete-plus’ settings.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a fix but a workaround.  I had the same issue.  The best i could do was to change my snippet from `log` to `l.`

The period at the end causes the autocomplete+ dialog window to close, but pressing tab still triggers the snippet.